# Angular 7 dynamic Reactive Form from JSON how to custom align fields

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm developing a dynamic Reactive form in Angular 7 taking reference from a [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@mail.bahurudeen/create-a-dynamic-form-with-configurable-fields-and-validations-using-angular-6-994db56834da), I am able to create a form but I'm unable to custom align the fields, all the form fields are placed below each other ,I want them to be next to each fields as in we put two fields in same  tag to achieve this in Template driven forms.[image].

My dynamic-form.component.ts file

```
@Component({
  exportAs: "dynamicForm",
  selector: "dynamic-form",
  template: `
  <form class="dynamic-form" [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSubmit($event)">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let field of fields;" dynamicField [field]="field" [group]="form">
  </ng-container>
  </form>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() fields: FieldConfig[] = [];

  @Output() submit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  form: FormGroup;

  get value() {
    return this.form.value;
  }
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.createControl();
  }

  onSubmit(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.submit.emit(this.form.value);
    } else {
      this.validateAllFormFields(this.form);
    }
  }

  createControl() {
    const group = this.fb.group({});
    this.fields.forEach(field => {
      if (field.type === "button") return;
      const control = this.fb.control(
        field.value,
        this.bindValidations(field.validations || [])
      );
      group.addControl(field.name, control);
    });
    return group;
  }

  bindValidations(validations: any) {
    if (validations.length > 0) {
      const validList = [];
      validations.forEach(valid => {
        validList.push(valid.validator);
      });
      return Validators.compose(validList);
    }
    return null;
  }

  validateAllFormFields(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
      const control = formGroup.get(field);
      control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
    });
  }
}
```

app.component.ts file

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { FieldConfig } from "./field.interface";
import { DynamicFormComponent } from "./components/dynamic-form/dynamic-form.component";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(DynamicFormComponent) form: DynamicFormComponent;
  regConfig: FieldConfig[] = [
    {
      type: "input",
      label: "First Name",
      inputType: "text",
      name: "name",
      validations: [
        {
          name: "required",
          validator: Validators.required,
          message: "Name Required"
        },
        {
          name: "pattern",
          validator: Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z]+$"),
          message: "Accept only text"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: "input",
      label: "Last Name",
      inputType: "text",
      name: "lastname",
      validations: [
        {
          name: "required",
          validator: Validators.required,
          message: "Last Name Required"
        },
        {
          name: "pattern",
          validator: Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z]+$"),
          message: "Accept only text"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: "input",
      label: "Email Address",
      inputType: "email",
      name: "email",
      validations: [
        {
          name: "required",
          validator: Validators.required,
          message: "Email Required"
        },
        {
          name: "pattern",
          validator: Validators.pattern(
            "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,4}$"
          ),
          message: "Invalid email"
        }
      ]
    },


    {
      type: "select",
      label: "Country",
      name: "country",
      value: "UK",
      options: ["India", "UAE", "UK", "US"]
    },
    {
      type: "checkbox",
      label: "Accept Terms",
      name: "term",
      value: true
    },
    {
      type: "button",
      label: "Save"
    }
  ];

  submit(value: any) {}
}
```

app.component.html

```
    <div class="form">
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
     General Partner Info
    </h1>
  </div>
  <dynamic-form [fields]="regConfig" (submit)="submit($event)">
  </dynamic-form>
  <!-- <div class="margin-top">
    {{ form.value | json }}
  </div> -->
</div>
```

Comment: Is this not simply a CSS issue? Can you have an encompassing element which uses flexbox and flex-wrap, sizing the inputs to allow for the wrap?

Comment: @WillAlexander, all the fields are driven dynamically from a json in a iteration till end of json , so I'm finding it difficult to have a CSS for individual field in the form

Comment: You don't need to add the class individually (although `ngClass` would allow you to) if all inputs have the same class and simply cascade through a flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete working example you can find out here in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vxcugy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Here, you need to use `display: flex`...

```
 .main{
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.body {
   width: 40%;
   margin: 10px;
}
.content{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

In above css, `flex-direction: row` and `flex-wrap: wrap` is very useful to break it down to new row.

Your template is...

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="main">
       <div  class="body" *ngFor ="let control of regConfig ; let i = index; let odd=odd; let even=even;" >
          <div class="content" [ngSwitch]="control.type">
           <ng-template ngSwitchCase="input">
             <label> {{ control.label }} </label>
             <input type="text" placeholder="text">
           </ng-template>
           <ng-template ngSwitchCase="select">
              <label> {{ control.label }} </label>
              <select>
                <option> default </option>
              </select>
           </ng-template>
           <ng-template ngSwitchCase="checkbox">
              <label> {{ control.label }} </label>
              <input type="checkbox" >
           </ng-template>
           <ng-template ngSwitchCase="button">
              <button> {{control.label}} </button>
           </ng-template>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE : 1**

If you have to use bootstrap classes then you can use `bootstrap-grid` system for break-point of different sizes.

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
          <div  class=" col-12 col-sm-6" *ngFor ="let control of regConfig ; let i = index; let odd=odd; let even=even;" >
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-12 " [ngSwitch]="control.type">
                  <ng-template ngSwitchCase="input">
                      <label> {{ control.label }} </label>
                      <input class="form-control"  type="text" placeholder="text">
                  </ng-template>
                  <ng-template ngSwitchCase="select">
                      <label> {{ control.label }} </label>
                      <select class="form-control">
                         <option> default </option>
                      </select>
                  </ng-template>
                  <ng-template ngSwitchCase="checkbox">
                     <div class = "form-check ">
                       <input class="form-check-input" [id]="control.name" type="checkbox" >
                       <label class="form-check-label" [for]="control.name"> {{ control.label }} </label>
                     </div>
                  </ng-template>
                  <ng-template ngSwitchCase="button">
                     <div class="form-group mt-2">
                         <button class="btn btn-primary"> {{control.label}}</button>
                     </div>
                  </ng-template>
               </div>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```